# Update on delimited list of id's and text

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a comma delimited list in the following format -

```
'id,text,id,text,id,text,etc...'
```

Example -

```
'1001,TextFor1001,1002,TextFor1002,1003,TextFor1003,etc...'
```

I need to update a SQL table like this -

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET mytable.textfor = 'TextFor1001' 
WHERE mytable.id = 1001;
```

How can I loop through the list without having to create an `UPDATE` statement for each entry?

**EDIT: TO EXPLAIN MY QUESTION FURTHER -**

I want to read through a string that looks like this-

```
'1001,TextFor1001,1002,TextFor1002,1003,TextFor1003,etc...'
```

And perform the equivalent of having multiple update statments like this -

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET mytable.textfor = 'TextFor1001' 
WHERE mytable.id = 1001;

UPDATE mytable 
SET mytable.textfor = 'TextFor1002' 
WHERE mytable.id = 1002;

UPDATE mytable 
SET mytable.textfor = 'TextFor1003' 
WHERE mytable.id = 1003;

etc...
```

Is there some kind of loop I can create that can read through the string, search for the id in a table, then update the record with the corresponding text value?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly going to be database specific. Please tell us the database you're using.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reply to the above comments, I've edited my question to hopefully explain further.

Comment: It's MYSql (I will add that to the question)

Answer (score -1):

The basic syntax of UPDATE query with WHERE clause is as follows:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

You can combine N number of conditions using AND or OR operators